# How can I fill missing data in my dataframe faster for a big dataset, and without a SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the count of people per day and per location. Without any missing data, I expect to have 4 lines per day: 2 locations and 2 genders. Some data is missing and should be replaced by the mean count, but only if that location has data for that gender on the day before.

If data is missing for more dan 1 day, I assume that there is supposed to be no data. So for example in my example dataframe: Day 2, Location X, Gender F should be filled, because Day 1, Location X, Gender F exists. But Day 4, Location Y, Gender F must stay empty, because Day 3, Location Y, Gender F does not exist.

- The code below works for this small dataframe, but it's really slow for my large dataset. Is there a way to do this faster?
- Can I avoid the SettingWithCopyWarnings in this case?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

data = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,1,2], 
                     'location': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'],
                     'gender': ['F', 'M', 'M','F', 'M','F', 'F','F','F'],
                     'count': random.sample(range(10, 30), 9)})

print(data.sort_values('day').reset_index(drop=True))


    day location    gender  count
0   1   X   F   17
1   1   X   M   10
2   1   Y   F   12
3   2   X   M   20
4   2   Y   F   15
5   3   X   F   24
6   3   X   M   29
7   4   X   F   11
8   5   X   F   14


data2 = pd.DataFrame()
for e, today in enumerate(list(set(data['day'].sort_values()))[1:]):
  yesterday = (list(set(data['day'].sort_values()))[e])
  today_df = data[(data['day']==today)].set_index(['location','gender'])
  yesterday_df = data[(data['day']==yesterday)].set_index(['location','gender'])

  today_missing = [[i[0],i[1]] for i in yesterday_df.index if i not in today_df.index]

  for i in today_missing:
    new_row = data[(data['day']==yesterday) & (data['location']==i[0]) & (data['gender']==i[1])]
    new_row['day'] = today
    new_row['count'] = int(np.mean(data['count'][(data['location']==i[0]) & (data['gender']==i[1])]))

    data2 = data2.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

data = data.append(data2).sort_values('day').reset_index(drop=True)
print(data)

    day location    gender  count
0   1   X   F   17
1   1   X   M   10
2   1   Y   F   12
3   2   X   M   20
4   2   Y   F   15
5   2   X   F   16
6   3   X   F   24
7   3   X   M   29
8   3   Y   F   13
9   4   X   F   11
10  4   X   M   19
11  5   X   F   14
```

Comment: Hi @Karen. Did the solution work out? If so and you wish, please mark it so this question can be marked as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, yes this solution works out perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be to re-generate the posible combinations of location, gender and day

```
df = data.set_index(['location', 'gender', 'day'])
         .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
          [['X', 'Y'], ['F', 'M'], range(1, 8)],
          names=['location', 'gender', 'day']))

                     count
location gender day       
X        F      1     17.0
                2      NaN
                3     24.0
                4     11.0
                5     14.0
                6      NaN
                7      NaN
         M      1     10.0
                2     20.0
                3     29.0
                4      NaN
                5      NaN
                6      NaN
                7      NaN
Y        F      1     12.0
                2     15.0
                3      NaN
                4      NaN
                5      NaN
                6      NaN
                7      NaN
         M      1      NaN
                2      NaN
                3      NaN
                4      NaN
                5      NaN
                6      NaN
                7      NaN
```

### 1: Solution filling with mean per `location, gender` group

```
df.groupby(['location', 'gender']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean(), limit=1)).dropna()

                         count
location gender day           
X        F      1    17.000000
                2    16.500000
                3    24.000000
                4    11.000000
                5    14.000000
         M      1    10.000000
                2    20.000000
                3    29.000000
                4    19.666667
Y        F      1    12.000000
                2    15.000000
                3    13.500000
```

### 2: Solution interpolating linearly between days

Another solution can be to interpolate between days within the `[location, gender]` groups, with a limit of 1 day filling:

```
df.interpolate(level=['location', 'gender'], limit=1).dropna()

                         count
location gender day           
X        F      1    17.000000
                2    20.500000
                3    24.000000
                4    11.000000
                5    14.000000
                6    12.666667
         M      1    10.000000
                2    20.000000
                3    29.000000
                4    25.600000
Y        F      1    12.000000
                2    15.000000
                3    15.000000
```

You can remove the multiindex doing `df.reset_index()`. Hope it serves.

Comment: Thank you! If data is missing for more dan 1 day, I assume that there is supposed to be no data. So I do not want to fill the NaN's in rows after a day with NaN. Y, F, 3 should be filled, but Y, F, 4 should stay empty. I will make this more clear in my question!

Comment: @Karen just edited the answer, hope it helps!